# The Mini-Max theorem for lattices

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm asking for help on an exercise in Davey and Priestleys's *Introduction to Lattices and Orders*. For those with the book, the exercise is specifically 2.9.

> Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with entries in a lattice $L$. Show that
>   $$\bigvee_{j=1}^n\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^m a_{ij}\right)\leq\bigwedge_{k=1}^m\left(\bigvee_{l=1}^n a_{kl}\right)$$

The left-hand-side represents the supremum of the cumulative infimums down the columns, and the right-hand-side represents the infimum of the cumulative supremums across the rows.

Now, I'm sure this could be accomplished by induction, but there has to be a cleaner way to do this. And I believe I found the result needed in the book to get a quick proof. For those with the reference, it's Lemma 2.27i). It reads:

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be ordered sets. Let $\phi:P\rightarrow Q$ be an order-preserving map. Suppose $S\subseteq P$ is such that $\bigvee S$ exists in $P$ and $\bigvee\phi(S)$ exists in $Q$. Then $\bigvee\phi(S)\leq\phi(\bigvee S)$

However, I'm having difficulty in seeing what my $P$ and $Q$ and $\phi$ would be here from looking at the matrix $A$.

I think $P$ would be $L^m$ with its product order, and that $Q$ is $L^n$ with its product order. But then again, the inequality above only concerns elements of $L$ and not $L^m$ or $L^n$. So, I'm stuck.

Any help in completing this exercise is appreciated. Or a hint in the right direction would be nice if my approach is flawed.

Comment: I'm not sure about the possibility of this lemma application in order to solve this exercise. I think the same approach as with usual distributive inequality can be applied here without induction and big calculations. Start with $\bigwedge_{i = 1}^m a_{ij} \leqslant a_{kj} \leqslant \bigvee_{l = 1}^n a_{kl}$, for all $k = \overline{1, m}, j = \overline{1, n}$.

Comment: That was helpful. Could you post that as an answer? Even a 'hint-answer'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to use the same approach which is used when proving usual distributive inequality. Start with the following inequalities:
$$\bigwedge_{i = 1}^m a_{ij} \leqslant a_{kj} \leqslant \bigvee_{l = 1}^n a_{kl},\  k = \overline{1, m},\ j = \overline{1, n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Remember that, by definition of $\bigvee$, any inequality of the form $\bigvee_px_p\leq y$ is equivalent to saying that $x_p\leq y$ for every $p$.  Similarly, any inequality of the form $w\leq\bigwedge_qz_q$ is equivalent to saying that $w\leq z_q$ for every $q$. In the situation of your question, both of these facts can be applied to simplify the problem. Then you can finish the job with Random Jack's hint.

Answer (score 1):

the combination of the above two replies yields:

$\hspace{1em} \bigvee_{j=1}^n\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^m a_{ij}\right)\leq\bigwedge_{k=1}^m\left(\bigvee_{l=1}^n a_{kl}\right)
\\
\equiv\hspace{4em} \{ \text{$\vee$-characterization: } \bigvee X \leq u \equiv (\forall x \in X \bullet x \leq u)\}
\\
\hspace{1em}\forall j \in 1..n \bullet
 \bigwedge_{i=1}^m a_{ij}\leq\bigwedge_{k=1}^m\left(\bigvee_{l=1}^n a_{kl}\right)
\\
\equiv\hspace{4em} \{ \text{$\land$-characterization: } l \leq \bigwedge X \equiv (\forall x \in X \bullet l \leq x)\}
\\
\hspace{1em}\forall j \in 1..n \bullet \forall k \in 1..m \bullet
 \bigwedge_{i=1}^m a_{ij}\leq\bigvee_{l=1}^n a_{kl}
\\
\Leftarrow\hspace{4em} \{ \text{$\leq$-transitivity} \}
\\
\hspace{1em}\forall j \in 1..n \bullet \forall k \in 1..m \bullet
 \bigwedge_{i=1}^m a_{ij}\leq a_{kj} \leq\bigvee_{l=1}^n a_{kl}
\\
\equiv\hspace{4em} \{ \text{Weakening/strengthening: }\forall x \in X \bullet \bigwedge X \leq x \leq \bigvee X \}
\\\hspace{1em} \mathsf{ true }
$

Hope this helps :)